# Logging off doesn't reflect deleted files to server

Tags: windows-7, roaming-profiles

When a user deletes a file in their profile, should the deleted files also be deleted on the server where their roaming profile is stored?

My users are seeing the files they deleted re-created in their profile next time they log on.

I have also seen this in a quick test I have done with a new user account on a fresh Win 7 install in a VM.

I never created the domain, so could it have been set this way??

Comment: Have you confirmed (by checking the registry on the client) that it is successfully syncing back?

Comment: No... how or rather where would I do that?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the event viewer. Maybe from the "user profile service".